# Does kernel regression preserve monotonicity?

Tags: st.statistics, inequalities, norms, kernels

Consider the Kernel regression estimator:

$$\hat{y}(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{K(x-x_i)y_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n{K(x-x_i)}},$$

where $x,x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $y_1,\dots,y_n\in\mathbb{R}$, where $K:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is a strictly positive valued, differentiable kernel function, with a unique maximum at $0$.

Suppose further that for all $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, if $x_i\le x_j$ then $y_i \le y_j$.

Is it the case that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$:

$$\frac{\partial\hat{y}(x)}{\partial x} \ge 0?$$

It seems obvious in the $d=1$ case, but even there I haven't been able to prove it. It's unclear to me if it holds for $d>1$. If it only holds under additional assumptions on $K$ I'd be interested in them.

---

Note, this was originally posted on math.stackexchange here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612590/does-kernel-regression-preserve-monotonicity but it attracted no answers even after a bounty was posted.

---

Notation:

$\frac{\partial \hat{y}(x)}{\partial x}$ is the column vector of partial derivatives of $\hat{y}(x)$, i.e. the (transposed) Jacobian.

For vectors $a=[a_1,\dots,a_d]^\top$ and $b=[b_1,\dots,b_d]^\top$, $a\le b$ if and only if $a_i \le b_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,d\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false in general even for $d=1$. E.g., let 
$$K=f_r+f_s,$$
where $f_t$ is the density of $N(0,t^2)$. Then for $x_i=y_i=i$ ($\forall i=1,\dots,n$) and
$$(n,r,s,x_*)=\Big(3,\frac{427}{215},\frac{1}{1547},\frac{472}{473}\Big)$$
we have 
$$\hat y'(x_*)=-527.1\ldots<0.$$

Here is the graph $\{(x,\hat y(x))\colon\frac{471}{473}\le x\le\frac{475}{473}\}$:

[image]

We see a very narrow dip.

---

However, $\hat y'\ge0$ if $K$ is log concave. Indeed, letting 
$$k_i:=K(x-x_i)\quad\text{and}\quad k'_i:=K'(x-x_i),$$
we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
2\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n k_i\Big)^2\hat y'(x)
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n(k'_i y_i k_j-k_i y_i k'_j+k'_j y_j k_i-k_j y_j k'_i) \\ 
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n(y_i-y_j)\Big(\frac{k'_i}{k_i}-\frac{k'_j}{k_j}\Big)k_ik_j\ge0,
\end{aligned}\tag{1}
$$
because $y_i$ is increasing in $i$ and 
$$\frac{k'_i}{k_i}=(\ln K(x-x_i))' \tag{2}$$
is increasing in $i$; the latter holds because $x_i$ is increasing in $i$ and $(\ln K)'$ is decreasing (since $K$ is log concave). (In particular, any normal density is log concave.)

---

---

In the case $d>1$, the desired monotonicity fails to hold in general even when $K$ is log concave. E.g., let 
$$K(u_1,\dots,u_d):=\exp\{u_1u_2-u_1^2-\cdots-u_d^2\},$$
$n=2$, $x_1=(0,\dots,0)$, $x_2=(0,1,0,\dots,0)$, $y_1=0$, and $y_2=1$. 
Then $(\partial_1\ln K)(u_1,\dots,u_d)=u_2-2u_1$, where $\partial_1$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to the first coordinate. On the other hand (cf. (1) and (2)), $(\partial_1\hat y)(0,\dots,0)$ equals $l'_2-l'_1$ in sign, where 
$$l'_1:=(\partial_1\ln K)(0,\dots,0)=0$$
and 
$$l'_2:=(\partial_1\ln K)(0,-1,0,\dots,0)=-1<0=l'_1.$$
So, $(\partial_1\hat y)(0,\dots,0)<0$, as claimed.

---

---

Looking back at (1), it is clear that the necessary and sufficient condition for the desired monotonicity is that the appropriate analogs of $\frac{k'_i}{k_i}-\frac{k'_j}{k_j}$ be $\ge0$ whenever for the corresponding $x_i$ and $x_j$ we have $x_i\ge x_j$. In particular, this will happen if $K$ is the product of log-concave functions of one coordinate each.

Here we of course need to assume that that $x_i$'s are linearly ordered, so that, without loss of generality, $x_i\le x_j$ if $i<j$. Indeed, suppose e.g. that $x_1=(1,0,\dots,0)$, $y_1=1$, $x_i=(0,1,0,\dots,0)$ and $y_i=0$ for $i=2,\dots,n$. Then the implication $x_i\le x_j\implies y_i\le y_j$ holds for all $i,j$. This implication will also hold if we replace here $y_1$ by $-1$. But then $\hat y$ will change in sign, and hence its monotonicity pattern will change to the opposite one.

Comment: In the multivariate log-concave case, your expression for $\hat{y}'(x)$ goes through exactly as here, but the final $\ge 0$ might not, if I'm understanding correctly. There will be some $i,j$ for which $x_i \ngeq x_j$ and $x_j \ngeq x_i$, thus for those pairs you can't guarantee anything about the sign of the product.

Do you have a counter-example for the claim with a log-concave $K$ and $d>1$?

Comment: @cfp : In the multivariate case, you left the meaning of $\frac{\partial\hat{y}(x)}{\partial x}$ and the meaning of the inequalities $x_i\le x_j$ undefined. Until you have done that, it is of course impossible to say anything about the multivariate case.

Comment: In my literature, there's no ambiguity over the meanings of these things! $\frac{\partial \hat{y}(x)}{\partial x}$ is the column vector of partial derivatives of $\hat{y}(x)$, i.e. the (transposed) Jacobian. For vectors $a=[a_1,\dots,a_d]^\top$ and $b=[b_1,\dots,b_d]^\top$, $a\le b$ if and only if $a_i \le b_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,d\}$.

Comment: @cfp : I have now given a counter-example with a log-concave $K$ for $d>1$.

Comment: Could there be even stronger assumptions on $K$ under which montonicity survives with $d>1$?

Comment: @cfp : Looking at (1), it is clear that the necessary and sufficient condition is that the appropriate analogs of $\frac{k'_i}{k_i}-\frac{k'_j}{k_j}$ be of the same sign as $y_i-y_j$. In particular, this will happen if $K$ is the product of log-concave functions of one coordinate each. To me, this coordinate-wise approach seems quite unnatural, though, since it depends on the choice of the basis.

Comment: Doesn't the monotonicity criteria already depend on the choice of basis? In context $K$ being a product of coordinate wise kernels is quite natural. (For one thing, choosing a different kernel bandwidth per coordinate by e.g. cross validation would already be difficult. Choosing a full kernel "covariance matrix" would be near impossible.) It sounds like your previous comment completes the answer, though I don't entirely see how you get round my first comment above. You might want to update your answer with this last part for completeness. (Thanks in any case!)

Comment: @cfp : I see now that the coordinate-wise approach may actually make sense in practice. I have also added my latter comment to the answer.

Comment: I still do not understand this final comment. You seem to be assuming that $x_i \le x_j \leftrightarrow y_i \le y_j$, but the implication only goes in one way ($x_i \le x_j \rightarrow y_i \le y_j$). They are equivalent if and only if $d=1$.

Comment: @cfp : I don't think I used a two-way implication. Anyway, I have now edited that piece a bit. I think it should be clearer now.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want $(y_i-y_j)\Big(\frac{k'_i}{k_i}-\frac{k'_j}{k_j}\Big)$ to be positive for all $i,j$. I.e. you need that the sign of $(y_i-y_j)$ is equal to the sign of $\Big(\frac{k'_i}{k_i}-\frac{k'_j}{k_j}\Big)$. In the univariate case, you can assume WLOG that BOTH $x_i$ and $y_i$ are increasing in $i$. In the multivariate case, you can only assume that $y_i$ is increasing in $i$. However, any individual coordinate of $x_i$ may not be increasing in $i$. [continued]

Comment: For example, suppose $y_1=1$, $y_2=2$, $y_3=3$, $y_4=4$, $x_1=[0,0]$, $x_2=[1,0]$, $x_3=[0,1]$, $x_4=[1,1]$. Then the first coordinate of $x_i$ is $0,1,0,1$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: (Notation: in the multivariate case $k_i'$ is a vector, and all operations work elementwise.)

Comment: @cfp : I have added a paragraph at the end of the answer to address your latter comments.

Comment: The problem is that there's no reason why $\le$ should be a linear order on $x_1,\dots,x_n$! And if the DGP was such that for any $n$, $\le$ was a linear order on $x_1,\dots,x_n$, then $\hat{y}(x)$ would be an inconsistent estimator of $y(x)$ over the entire domain, as all observations would be concentrated on a single (1d) path through $X$.

Comment: At most, I can guarantee that $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ has a minimum and maximum within the set (i.e. an element weakly smaller than all others, and an element weakly larger than all others).

Comment: @cfp : If you don't have a linear order over the $x_i$'s, then, as I showed, in general you cannot expect the monotonicity of $\hat y$. Having a minimal and maximal $x_i$ will not help, as one can make most of the $x_i$'s mutually incomparable with one another. Philosophically, because your order on the $x_i$'s is very weak, your condition of the monotonicity of the map $x_i\to y_i$ is also very weak, and you cannot possibly get much out of it.